# How to create Docker image,Dockerfile of LAravel application from existing docker environment for Laravel

Tags: laravel, docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I have dockervel environment  ,**docker container for Laravel** , and I really struggled to make it work on my machine.

The way **I used the dockervel** **image** is described here http://www.spiralout.eu/2015/12/dockervel-laravel-development.html

I have **developed an application** including Behat for BDD and PHPUnit testing **in this environmen**t and I have to **make an image from it and say how to use It**. *I am confused how to create Dockerfile ?*

any help is appreciated

Comment: [Documentation on Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, dockervel is not a single image. It consists of sevelar images orchestrated together by docker-compose (see docker-compose.yml). And the reason for that is that you don't need all the parts every time (eg. you don't load nodejs when all you want is to work with artisan). Also you can change parts (eg. you can change MySQL with Postgres).

If you want to share your project, the easy way is to share the entire dockervel folder (please omit the node_modules folder, you can recreate it with `dcomposer install`, as also the database folders).

If you realy want to make it a single dockerfile (not so good idea) you should combine each dockerfile into a single one and you will end up with a huge and not flexible container.

Comment: Aha,ok, he only needs to be able to run it ,including some unit testing. Questions:
**Which database folder(s) like dockervel/databse or dockervel/www/database or something else?
Here's what confuses me , if I deliver it like dockervel folder(for example via github),  he obviously doesn't need  to run all the steps from the dockervel tutorial ,but I'm not sure what does to make it behave propertly ?**  he needs  to run maybe, ./aliases.sh ,dup , dpermit , dartisan migrate ..?

Comment: The best way is to share only the www folder (without node_modules, vendor etc.)    The partner should git clone dockervel `git checkout builder`, clone your www folder to dockervel's www,`sudo su` `. ./aliases.sh` `dcomposer install` to recreate dependencies, `dpermit` to fix permitions , `dup` to run entire package and `dartisan migrate` to create the tables to his own database.     When you share a project you don't have to share the entire DB entries but you need to initiate the DB structure.

Comment: Am I  able to run some AngularJS?  I need to run  dnodejs npm install or something in addition?

Answer (score 2):

This is NOT the answer to your question but I had bit of struggle with dockervel as well and thought of simplifying the docker implementation for Laravel projects.

The result is https://github.com/purinda/docker-laravel

This gives you ability to easily communicate with Laravel CLI commands such as `artisan` and running unit tests through `phpunit` in a the docker environment using multi-container environment.